# How to prevent user from bypassing the quantity using the add button

Tags: php

In my button the user can add more quantity from his order. 
What I want is to prevent the user from adding more than the quantity left.
The button goes into the cart table. What I want is to connect the product_qty to the cart so that the user cannot abuse the add button.

> E.G. Item A ( 5 stocks left ) , User inputs 4 , but the user can abuse it using the button going from 4 to 8.

**my product table consists of**

`productid,
categoryid,
product_name,
product_price,
product_qty,
supplierid,`

**my cart table consists of**

```
cartid,
userid,
productid,
qty,
```

**This is my php file**

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        $newqty=$row['qty']+1;

        mysqli_query($conn,"update cart set qty='$newqty' where productid='$id'");

    }

?>
```

Comment: Just check when the user tries to change the number, and forbid him from doing so if he reaches his limits.

Comment: You should use prepared statements, you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul , yes the user can see the total stock

Comment: @jeroen i am new to programming , I just want to make a system even though the security is not well made , as of now I just want to make a functional system , just for me , i dont plan on releasing this

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to make sql queries each time the user clicks on “Add” button.

Comment: @EugeneR , sorry about that , i am quite new , i just want to finish my practice system

Comment: @Kim, not a problem. You can also limit maximum value for input using `max` option in it. In example, `<input max="<?=$inStock?>">`, where `$inStock` is the variable consists your value of total stock for this item.

Comment: @EugeneR , in my practice system , the user cannot input higher number than the quantity but can be bypass by pressing the add button.

Comment: @Kim, ok, so you can add `disabled` attribute to this button if value in input area is `=>` than in stock. It easily can be done with javascript.

Comment: Also, it looks that your project has a big architectural problems)

Comment: @EugeneR , can you please give me example . Here is my button code (<button type="button"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add_qty" value="<?php echo $row['productid']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i></button> )

Comment: @Kim, https://jsfiddle.net/ujkytwu2/6/ hope you know how to add javascript code to your page. Also, to add php variable to javascript's inStock you need to do like `var inStock = <?php echo $inStock;?>;`

Comment: @EugeneR can you help me modify my codes? I really am i confuse please

Comment: @Kim, hm, what is not clear for you in example I provided? You just need to add ids to your input and button tags, and add this javascript code to the end of your page inside script tag, `<script>javascript code</script>`

Comment: @EugeneR what should i add in my script?  add this jsfiddle.net/ujkytwu2/6?

Comment: @Kim, yeap, add javascript's code from it and replace inStock value as I explained above

Comment: @EugeneR ok i will try it tommorrow , thanks again , ill try coding again tommorow. I will ask you again tommorow can I ?

Comment: @Kim, yes, sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first check whether addition of the product exceeds the total stock or not, and then perform the `UPDATE` operation accordingly.

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM product NATURAL JOIN cart where productid = '$id' AND userid = YOUR_USER_ID");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            if(($row['qty'] + 1) <= $row['product_qty']){
                $newqty = $row['qty'] + 1;
                mysqli_query($conn,"update cart set qty='$newqty' where productid='$id'");
                // your code
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Sidenotes**:

- It is not a good idea to call SQL query/submit form for every addition of product. Let user decide the total quantity of the product user wants and then send the accumulated value to database. Use JavaScript for this.
- Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your queries are susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @Kim, I've updated my answer, please test your application with the updated code snippet. Also, in the query, don't forget to replace YOUR_USER_ID with the actual userid.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul why are you joining cart table? You have a productid and you do not need anything else to get its product_qty.

Comment: @Kim, please explain *nothing happens*. Are you seeing any error? Have you changed YOUR_USER_ID with the actual userid in the query?

Comment: @EugeneR Without JOIN we would end up having 3 queries, one to get total stock, one to get current quantity from the cart(so that we could check overflow condition) and one to update the cart.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, ah, ok. Anyway, Kim tolds that the total stock already is on the page, so this value can be taken from there.

Comment: @EugeneR OP has to confirm where exactly it's stored, is it in a variable, session etc. I'll update my answer accordingly, right now OP has to say a bit more than *nothing happens*.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul  , when i click the add button , the quantity does not go up

Comment: @Kim That's probably because requested quantity is exceeding total stock. Paste your actual code snippet in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here. Additionally, you can put couple of `echo` statements to debug this issue further, like this: [https://pastebin.com/nWw9PWAC](https://pastebin.com/nWw9PWAC)

Comment: @Kim [As I said in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666459/how-to-prevent-user-from-bypassing-the-quantity-using-the-add-button/49667020?noredirect=1#comment86386241_49667020), put couple of echo statements to debug this issue further, like this: https://pastebin.com/nWw9PWAC. Did you see any error message? Also, I see you didn't change YOUR_USER_ID with your actual userid in the query, change that as well.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i did change it , it works slightly well , but now it works like this (E.G. total stocks: 5 , the user can add using the add button until 4 , it should go up to 5 but not higher than 5)

Comment: @Kim, Ah, I see the problem now. `if(($row['qty'] + 1) < $row['product_qty']){` should be `if(($row['qty'] + 1) <= $row['product_qty']){`, missed `=` sign there. I've updated my answer, it should work fine now.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul , sir rajdeep thank you very much , you help me big time , your the only one who answered my weird question. Thank you :)

Comment: @Kim, Glad I could help. :-) Please *accept* the answer to close the question, otherwise this question will be floating around as open question. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)